# Is this sentence grammatically correct or not?

Tags: present-perfect

While reading an article I came across this:

> After the process has finished it is not possible to know where it was running.

Is this sentence considered grammatically correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more correct to use 'once' instead of 'after' in this case because one condition causes the other; it's only possible to know where the process is running while it is running.

**'Once the process has finished, it is no longer possible to know where it was running'.**